# Leer un zip dentro de otro zip en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, zip

Tengo un archivo zip llamado A.zip, este archivo tiene dentro mas archivos zip llamados A_001.zip, A_002.zip.... Y dentro de cada uno de estos zip hay varios archivos .txt que quiero leer y poner en diferentes arrays

Lo que pasa es que no tengo ni idea de como hacer que Al seleccionar el archivo A.zip en mi web, me haga todo el proceso descrito anteriormente, no se si tengo que usar la banda del servidor "Server side" o la banda del cliente "Client side"...

Comment: Tip: [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/), y una vez que obtienes la lista de archivos contenidos en el primer *ZIP*, los evalúas nuevamente, uno por uno, para aplicar nuevamente la utilería si corresponde. En caso contrario, haces lo que necesitas con los archivos **.txt**, es decir, enviarlos a un arreglo.

Al estar programando en *JavaScript*, se estaría ejecutando en el lado del cliente, y por lo tanto debes de tener mucho cuidado con el consumo de recursos de memoria del usuario, te sugiero limitar el tamaño de los archivos.